# Can someone help me understand the logic and fix it for loading a map?

Tags: javascript, html

I am loading a map and add markers from a database to the canvas. When I first load the page, the function "load()" is called and I know the input 'form' is null because I have an alert in case form=null. When I press "search" in the form field, the "load" function is called and I know form!=null because I have a different alert. However after I press 'ok' for the different alert I can see that load is called again with form=null because the corresponding alert then pops up.

Here is the beginning of the load function in the head:

```
//Edit (adding more information for clarity)
//<![CDATA[
var map;
function load(form) {
    if (form != null) {
        alert("Form not null!");
    } else {
        alert("Form is null :-(");
    }


    var myOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(42, -70),
      zoom: 3,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),myOptions);
    // rest is edited out
}

function addMarkers() {
//************MAP WILL NOT GENERATE WITH THIS SECTION OR ADD MARKERS*************
            microAjax("genjsonphp.php?stdt="+costlow+"&enddt="+costhigh, function(data) {
              var json = JSON.parse(data);
              var points = json;

            for (var i = 0; i<points.length; i++)
                {
                var point = points[i];
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(point.LocationLat)/1000000,parseFloat(point.LocationLon)/1000000);
                    var marker = createMarker(point.House,
                         point.Place,
                         point.Cost,
                         latlng,
                         map);
               }
        });
//************************************************************************************  
    }


function createMarker(House, Place, Cost, latlng, mapsent)
{
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                       position: latlng,
                       map: mapsent,
                       title: House  
                       });
      marker.info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: House + '<br />' + Place + '<br />' + Cost
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
        marker.info.open(mapsent, marker);
    });
    return marker;
}

//]]>
```

Here are the fields to load the map and narrow the search criteria:

```
        <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="2" ALIGN="Center" WIDTH=80%>
       <body onload="load()" onunload="GUnload()">
         <TR>
         <TD>
            <div id="map" style="width: 1250px; height: 750px"></div>
         </TD>
         <TD>

            <form method="post">
            <input type="text" name="search_criteria" id="search_criteria" /> 
            <!--button to modify search criteria-->
            <button type="submit" id="narrow_search_form" name="narrow_search_form" onClick = "addMarkers()">Search</button>
            </form>
            </body>
          </TD>
          </TR>
         </TABLE>
```

How do I fix my code so that when the search button is pressed the load function is called once and the information in the form is passed to the load function?

Comment: Why do you have a body tag inside a table tag?

Comment: first, is this the real structure? please note that the `table` is containing a `body` start tag, and not closing. please paste a more constructed snippet of code.

Comment: sorry, tried to just post the essential. I'll add the rest.

Comment: Note you are not pasing anythign to load function ONLOAD event, so it for sure will be NULL. Also if you want to check the text put into search box, thats not the way...

Comment: @Kedor I understand that's null when I first start the page. When I press the search button information is then passed to the function, but then the page reloads and null is sent again. How do I change that? What do you mean in your last sentence?

Comment: well, lots of issues here, first make sure your HTML is valid - you can do it at the [W3C markup validation service](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input). second, check for an undefined variable (`if (form)`) rather then for a null pointer (`if (form != null)`). let me know how it's going on.

Comment: hmm, on page reload? You need to use PHP then, and use php to pass variable from FORM to javascript function. Javascript do not save variables trough page reloads

Comment: @Kedor In the load function I am calling a PHP file. I need the information from the form to call the php file and narrow my search in an SQL database. However, after I make the query, the map and form are reloaded and the 'load' function is called again with load()<--where nothing is getting passed.

Comment: Well, as i would love to help, i have no idea what you are trying to achieve, what should be the result. Its hard to guess. I got many ideas, but i can't ask "is it what you wanted?" for every one of them. You can use `load('<?php echo $somephpvar; ?>')` to pass variable from php to java. But you are passing this.form in code, so there is no such thing in php to store that i guess. What are you really trying to check using `form!=null`? Is something typed to search box? Or something else?

Comment: Hmm, sorry the question is not more clear. I have a map that is loaded using the load() function and markers are added to the map. I want to have some fields so that the user can pass more information to the load() function and narrow the search for the number of markers returned. I probably left out too much information to make the question clear. If that doesn't make sense, I will try to rewrite the question to be clearer later.

Comment: Ah, now i get it. You can achieve that in 2 ways. Just javascript, without reloading page, or with reloading using php. The code of load function would be usefull. Anyway, as word(s) typed to searchbox are used to narrow sql answer, then you need to pass it to your Ajax/php function inside load(). I dont see problem here. Just use $_POST['search_criteria'] to pass or just to use it inside load(). Give me some time, ima try create a example page and will get back to you soon

Comment: Okay. As i was saying, you didn't provide the load code, so i am not sure how are you creating markers, using sql database. So i created my own way. [Working example](http://81.190.82.171/Google%20Maps%20Api/) <- here is an example. Try putting "poland" or "freeway" to box, and it will show only some of the markers. Everything is done using form, php and mysql database. Is that what you want? If yes, i will post whole code. It IS reloading the page. LEAVING IT EMPTY, AND SUBMITING WILL SHOW ALL MARKERS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. I decided to write an answer, because i started creating too many comments.

[Working example](http://symposium.ugu.pl/GoogleMapsApi/index.php) <<- use that one, not the comment one. Cuz one from comment was my local one, forgot to upload it somewhere, and it will be gone once i turn off PC.

Depending on what you put to the searchbox, you get only markers containing - in some way or another - searched term/word. 
**Try putting *"poland"* or *"freeway"***

**That part is made with PHP:**

```
if($_POST['search_criteria'] == "" || !isset($_POST['search_criteria'])) $result = mysql_query("SELECT lat, lng, search_crit, something_else from markers");
else $result = mysql_query("SELECT lat, lng, search_crit, something_else from markers where search_crit = '$_POST[search_criteria]'");
```

So depending if you put anything to search box, you search and take markers from database, **which "search_crit" column is same as word written into searchbox**. And that's pretty much everything. If you want, you can pass it as an variable to load:

```
load('<? echo $_POST["search_criteria"]; ?>')
```

and then use it in function as some parameter you are using to compare markers. As i said, i would need your load function, to know how are you creating markers, and comparing them.

**Also, i would delete** `load(this.form)` from onclick at button, because whatever it does, its gone right away with page reload anyway. As submit button will submit/reload page after being pressed.
**If you want to have it just for checking purposes,** pass something else to function than whole form. Just textbox value for example. [Like here!](http://jsfiddle.net/NDxAF/1/) (*changed button to not submitting one, for showing purposes*)

Anything unclear? Want whole file/source code? Just comment below, ima update the answer.

Source file, saved as *.txt so you can see the actual code: [Source code](http://symposium.ugu.pl/GoogleMapsApi/index.txt)
(*changed login and password when connecting mysql database so i wont show it to whole world.*)

Comment: I hope it will help. The second way, is to always create all markers on the map, and then just filter/hide some with javascript without refreshing. Anyway, got any questions, just ask!

Comment: I added more information above. Is there a way to call "addMarkers()" without reloading the entire page when the submit button is pressed? Your example works the way I want. Im checking it out and trying to get my page to act the same way

Comment: Well ofc it is. It looks like javascript function with use of Ajax. Just use `<input type="button" value="A button" onclick="addMarkers()">` and it will be called on this button click. On anything else just use `onclick="addMarkers()"`. But in that case, it will create already existing markers, as you are not hiding them, nor reloading the map, so it will just duplicate existing markers.